# Rails: Queue Email until user let it send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to queue all email called by the controller until a user let it send?

It seems that `deliver_later` can only specify a time, But I want to wait until I let it send out.

Comment: I end up saving those data to a file, when user initial the sending just read the file and send it. It seems there is no build in or gem for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails approach would be to *not* send it until the user initiates such a sending action, then generate and send it.

If you need to pre-send it for some reason, capture whatever data is necessary for the rendering to occur then save that in a table for future use. When the user initiates the sending, make the final send call with that data.